# Can I get the index of the tab being closed on a QTabWidget in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt5

I am currently making an app with tabbed text editors (QTextEdit objects) and I want to be able to get the index of the tab that is being closed. I looked at the documentation, but the only index that can be returned is that of the current tab that is opened. Can I do this?

Currently, when I am on one tab and I try to close another, the tab I am on closes instead. This is because currently, I pass the current tab as the one that will be closed.

Here's the current close tab function that I have:

```
connect(ui->tabWidget_2, &QTabWidget::tabCloseRequested, this, [=]() {
    MainWindow::closeEditor(ui->tabWidget_2->currentIndex());
});

...

void MainWindow::closeEditor(int index) {
paths.erase(paths.begin() + index);
edits.erase(edits.begin() + index);
ui->tabWidget_2->removeTab(index);
}
```

Is there a way to replace the ***currentIndex()*** with a method that returns the index of the tab being closed?

Comment: The [signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtabwidget.html#tabCloseRequested) passes the index explicitly.  Why not just use that?

Comment: In other words, change `connect(ui->tabWidget_2, &QTabWidget::tabCloseRequested, this, [=]() {
    MainWindow::closeEditor(ui->tabWidget_2->currentIndex());
});` to `connect(ui->tabWidget_2, &QTabWidget::tabCloseRequested, this, &MainWindow::closeEditor);`